# Django: How to use a modal to delete an object?

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

On the index page for a list of food objects I've included a button to delete an object that is not used. The delete button launches a Bootstrap 5 modal delete form. But when I click the Delete button, the error thrown includes the name of index page. In the code below, where & how can this be fixed?

Expected url on delete: `.../food/1/delete`

Page not found: `Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/food/foodIndex/1/delete`

It may be worth noting that the 404 error considers the request to be `GET` rather than `POST`

[I'm attempting to learn Python & Django by recreating a working PHP project. All of the HTML & javascript comes from that project.]

food/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('foodIndex/', views.foodIndex, name="foodIndex"),
    path('<int:id>/edit/', views.foodEdit, name="foodEdit"),
    path('<int:id>/foodDelete/', views.foodDelete, name = "foodDelete")
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Note: a `path('foodIndex/<int:id>/foodDelete/',...` does not solve the problem

Template included in ".../food/foodIndex.html":

```
{% if allFoods.count > 0 %}
    {% for food in allFoods %}
        <tr>
            <td data-foodid="{{ food.id }}">{{ food }}</td>
            <td><a class="btn p-0" href='{% url "food:foodEdit" food.id %}'>Edit</a></td>
            {% if food.used == False %}
            <td><button id='btn_delete' type="button" class="btn p-0" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-delete" data-bs-foodid='{{ food.id }}' data-bs-foodname='{{ food }}'>Delete</button></td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">no records found</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

Modal in ".../food/foodIndex.html":

```
<div id="modal-delete" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Delete food item</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <form >
                    <button id='food-delete' class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

delete form:

```
{<form method="POST" action="{% url 'food:foodDelete' pk=food.id %}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">
    <button class="btn">Delete</button>
</form>}
```

javascript for modal:

```
const deleteModal = document.getElementById('modal-delete');
deleteModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
    const button = event.relatedTarget
    const foodName = button.getAttribute('data-bs-foodname')
    const foodId = button.getAttribute('data-bs-foodid')
    const modalBodyInput = deleteModal.querySelector('.modal-body ')
    const modalFooterButtons= deleteModal.querySelector('form')

    modalBodyInput.textContent = `Confirm deletion of ${foodName}`
    modalFooterButtons.setAttribute('action',`${foodId}/delete`)
}
);
```

Comment: What is wrong with the [DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView) sir, it is very easier and straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the form on how you are building your URL.

```
deleteModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
    ...
    modalFooterButtons.setAttribute('action',`${foodId}/delete`)
}
);
```

That will always yield just `some-id/delete` as your action, you are not building the full path. One simple solution would be to use [`DTL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#the-django-template-language) to build your `URL` using [`reverse resolution`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls), just like in your `delete form` code block.

But, instead, use that as an attribute of the table delete button (you can just replace `data-bs-foodid`)

```
<button 
    id='btn-delete' 
    class="btn-warning" 
    data-bs-toggle="modal" 
    data-bs-target="#modal-delete" 
    data-bs-foodname='{{ food }}' 
    data-bs-url="{% url 'food:foodDelete' food.id %}"
>
    Delete
</button>
```

Then, we retrieve it and set those values on the form using the same method with JavaScript:

```
deleteModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
    ...
    const deleteForm= deleteModal.querySelector('form');
    const url = button.getAttribute('data-bs-url');
    deleteForm.setAttribute('action', url);
    deleteForm.setAttribute('method', 'post');
});
```

### Full example

foodIndex.html (Table with Foods)

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% if allFoods.count > 0 %}
        {% for food in allFoods %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{food.name}}</th>
            <td><button>Edit</button></td>
            <td>
                <button 
                    id='btn-delete' 
                    class="btn-warning" 
                    data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                    data-bs-target="#modal-delete" 
                    data-bs-foodname='{{ food }}' 
                    data-bs-url="{% url 'food:foodDelete' food.id %}"
                >
                    Delete
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">no records found</td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

foodIndex.html (Modal - Note `{% csrf_token %}`)

```
<div id="modal-delete" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Delete food item</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <form>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button id='food-delete' class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

foodIndex.html (script)

```
<script>
    const deleteModal = document.getElementById('modal-delete');

    deleteModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
        const button = event.relatedTarget;
        const foodName = button.getAttribute('data-bs-foodname');
        const url = button.getAttribute('data-bs-url');
        const modalBodyInput = deleteModal.querySelector('.modal-body ');

        modalBodyInput.textContent = `Confirm deletion of ${foodName}`;

        const deleteForm= deleteModal.querySelector('form');
        deleteForm.setAttribute('action', url);
        deleteForm.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks immensely for this answer! No longer do I get the 404 error. Need to study it more closely to see why.